# Php equivalent mcrypt_get_block_size( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 ,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); in ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Need small help, can you please tell me Ruby equivalent for following code which is in php.

```
mcrypt_get_block_size( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 ,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
```

I found answer for myself.

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
cipher.block_size
```

Comment: how about this one https://github.com/kingpong/ruby-mcrypt ?

Comment: Looking for plan ruby function without gem.

Comment: I think here you get all the informations you need https://www.elitmus.com/blog/technology/gotchas-while-syntactically-translating-aes-encryption-logic-from-php-to-ruby/ . You can't translate it strate from php to ruby. This blog post describes why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for myself.

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
cipher.block_size
```